# Shakespeare Programming Language Help - Windows

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, interpreter, shakespeare-lang

I've recently gotten interested in the esoteric programming language *Shakespeare Programming Language (SPL)* and have tried to install the only windows-friendly interpreter I could find, from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shakespearelang/0.2.0

It was my first time installing pip and python (3.6) as a whole, although I believe I have installed everything correctly.

When I try to interpret a legitimate SPL file with:

```
shakespeare run helloworld.py
```

I get the error:

```
File "c:\...\shakespearelang\shakespeare_interpreter.py", line 151, in run_event
self._character_by_name(name).on_stage = True
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'on_stage'
```

Everything else in the interpreter seems to work properly except calling the someone to "the stage".

Any fix to this error or an alternative windows-friendly compiler/interpreter would be great.

Comment: You should report this to the developer at https://github.com/zmbc/shakespearelang/issues

Comment: You could try using [this online SPL interpreter](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=25672).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Any fix to this error or an alternative windows-friendly
>   compiler/interpreter would be great.

[Here is an alternative](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=SPL) you could try.  It is a web-based "IDE" for building and running SPL programs.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the latest release on GitHub.

```
git clone https://github.com/zmbc/shakespearelang
pip install ./shakespearelang
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the file should be `helloworld.spl` instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem based on the OP's error message.